# Swift UIActionSheet crashes on iPad?

Tags: ipad, swift, uiactionsheet

I m currently running into complete frustrations as i can't find any error, but my ActionSheet crashes on iPad but works well on iPhone here is the code of the action

```
if (view.annotation.title as String!) == "San Francisco" {

                currentLat = 37.615223
                    currentLong = -122.389977

                url = "www.google.de"

                let action:UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Change Map Type", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Back", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Product Page", "Video")
                action.showInView(self.view)
                action.tag = 0
                VideoID = "XXXXXX"


            }
```

So the action that should be handled is

```
if actionSheet.tag == 0{
            if buttonIndex == 1{ performSegueWithIdentifier("showShop", sender: self) }
            if buttonIndex == 2{ UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(youtubeVideoID)")) }
            //if buttonIndex == 2{ performSegueWithIdentifier("showYoutube", sender: self) }

        }
```

The Youtube one works fine, on iPhone and iPad, the "showShop" does work fine on iPhone but not on iPad

The "showShop" Segue forward to my ViewControllerShopView that looks like

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerShopView: UIViewController {
/* ################################################## IBOutlets ################################################## */
    @IBOutlet weak var activity3: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
/* ################################################## viewDidLoad ################################################## */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadurl()
    }
/* ################################################## didReceiveMemoryWarning ################################################## */
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        println("memory warning")
    }
/* ################################################## viewWillAppear ################################################## */
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        loadurl()
    }
/* ################################################## loadurl func ################################################## */
    func loadurl(){
        var loadingurl = "google.com"
        var homeurl = "google1.com"
        loadingurl = url
        let webviewURL = NSURL(string: loadingurl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: webviewURL)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
/* ################################################## HomeButton ################################################## */
    @IBAction func Reload(sender: AnyObject) {

        var loadingurl = "google.com"
        var homeurl = "google1.com"
        loadingurl = url
        let webviewURL = NSURL(string: loadingurl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: webviewURL)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
/* ################################################## Activity Indicator ################################################## */
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : UIWebView){activity3.startAnimating()}
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView){activity3.stopAnimating()}



}
```

but the Segue never been done on iPad, it simply crashes on the Segue.

Anyone a idea what could be wrong?

Comment: on iOS8+ you need to use the `UIActionController` instead, the `UIActionSheet` and `UIAlertView` are deprecated, more info about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html, however you have not mentioned which iOS versions are affected...

Comment: @holex how my action sheet must look as actioncontroller?

Comment: they look the same, because the `UIAlertController` is a 'merged' (or 'combined' if you'd like) version of `UIActionSheet` and `UIAlertView` in one class, so the end-user won't spot the difference, but under the hood (in your code) you need to handle such deprecation if your project supports both iOS7 and iO8.

Comment: @holex i mean look like in code :) sorry.
Currently it only supports ios8

Comment: no, the `UIAlertController` works totally different than the old `UIActionSheet` or `UIAlertView` did. (**SORRY!** I mistyped the name of the class above!)

Comment: now i m complet confused :) so "there is no" easy work around for this to get it to ios8 on ipad?

Comment: no, in iOS7 you can use only `UIAlertView` or `UIActionSheet` but in iOS8 you have to use the `UIActionController` only. the implementation is different, you need to check which iOS version runs on the device in runtime to work with the proper classes.

Comment: @holex see post below

Comment: no, see _my_ post below. that is the proper way if you support both iOS7 and iOS8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61903/discussion-between-fabian-boulegue-and-holex).

Answer (score 7):

you need to check the system version in runtime if your project supports **both** iOS7 and iOS8; you can insert this snippet into any of your methods:

```
let systemVersion: NSInteger = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).integerValue
if systemVersion < 8 {
    // iOS7:
    let action:UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Change Map Type", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Back", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Product Page", "Video")
    action.tag = 0
    action.showInView(self.view)
} else {
    // iOS8:
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Change Map Type", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Back", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    let button1action: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Product Page", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> () in
        // doing something for "product page"
    })
    let button2action: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Video", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> () in
        // doing something for "video"
    })
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(button1action)
    alertController.addAction(button2action)

    // for iPAD support:
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.height / 2.0, 1.0, 1.0) // this is the center of the screen currently but it can be any point in the view

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and your class needs to conform the `UIActionSheetDelegate` for the `UIActionSheet` class:

```
extension ViewController : UIActionSheetDelegate {

    func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, didDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

        if actionSheet.tag == 0 {
            if buttonIndex == 1 {
                // doing something for "product page"
            } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
                // doing something for "video"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Getting a crash with

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController (<UIAlertController: 0x815c8c10>) of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet.

Comment: The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'

Comment: I just testet it on a new project with simulator with Xcode6 6A313 - works for iphone but crashes on ipad

Comment: Here is the clean sample project https://www.dropbox.com/s/54jqd8nsc67ll5g/test.zip?dl=0 works on iPhone but crashes on iPad

Answer (score -1):

also tried this

```
@IBAction func BTfindme(sender: AnyObject) {
        let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Test", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            }
        actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let ActionOne: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Action one", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
            }
        actionSheetController.addAction(ActionOne)

        let ActionTwo: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Action two", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
            }
        ActionTwo.addAction(choosePictureAction)
        self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and this also force a crash on ipad but not on iphone