# Swift Alert popup is appearing in simulator iphone4s(8.1), not iphone4s (7.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uialertcontroller

I have written code to display a simple alert popup when a button is clicked. When trying the app in simulator iPhone 4s (8.1), it's working as expected, but when trying in simulator iPhone 4s (7.1), the app keeps crashing.

Here the code:

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

```
    let controller = UIAlertController(title: "This is a title", message: "Hello, my friend", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Phew!", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    controller.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here's the error message:

The first line code (the one creating the "controller" constant) is highlighted in green with the message "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1,address=0x10)"

I would appreciate any help

Comment: you probably know the `UIAlertController` is available in iOS8+ only, which means it is not available in iOS7; a little reference which helps on you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037657/swift-uiactionsheet-crashes-on-ipad/26038730#26038730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIAlertController is only available in iOS 8.0 and on wards unfortunately, here is documentation and it states this on the right: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014538-CH1-SW2 
 I believe this replaced the now deprecated UIAlertView which can be found here  in Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertView 
 Swift doesn't like the old but consider and "if" clause and create both a UIAlertView and UIAlertController for the respective iOS system using the app.

Comment: Thanks Dom Bryan, I followed your recommended links and I managed a solution that is working now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertController is available for iOS >= 8.0

You have to use UIAlertView for iOS < 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to recommended links from Dom Bryan, I managed the following solution:

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

```
    if NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") == nil{
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "This is a title", message: "I am an iOS7 alert", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Phew!")
        alert.show()
    }else{
        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "This is a title", message: "Hello, my friend", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Phew!", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        controller.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And it's working fine on iOS7 and iOS8 devices